# Getting the average of a Value column based on Level column, and each previous level will be included in the next

Tags: google-sheets

I am playing a game, and I want to get the average value of the items available to you. As you level up, new items are available, and you still have access to items of the previous level.

I tried working with ChatGPT. It gave me a formula:

```
=QUERY(B:A, "SELECT A, AVG(B) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A")
```

Here is the table:

| Value | Level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 9 |
| 37 | 9 |
| 61 | 10 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 15 | 10 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 44 | 5 |
| 55 | 8 |
| 12 | 4 |
| 25 | 6 |
| 39 | 11 |
| 45 | 12 |
| 76 | 14 |
| 14 | 7 |
| 40 | 5 |
| 40 | 5 |
| 40 | 5 |
| 100 | 5 |
| 100 | 5 |
| 100 | 5 |

In this case, A and B in the aforementioned formula would be reversed.

I can't get it to include values from the previous levels. It gives me this:

| Level | avg Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 8.5 |
| 5 | 59.25 |
| 6 | 25 |
| 7 | 10.5 |
| 8 | 55 |
| 9 | 23 |
| 10 | 38 |
| 11 | 39 |
| 12 | 45 |
| 14 | 76 |

It is grouping by the level, which is a step in the right direction.. but it needs to also include previous levels. Without manually adding these values to each subsequent level, how do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by previous level?

Comment: So, we are leveling up in a video game. The values are the cost of an item. As we progress, we have access to more items, and we don't lose access to the previous level's items. At level 5, you should have access to the items from levels 1-4 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, B:B, "<="&E2)
```

It gets values of levels equal and lesser to the current level.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this formula, it gets the levels in the first line. Then with BYROW, it stacks the level with the value of AVERAGEIF. It'd calculate the average of A column based on B column being higher or equal than the level.

```
=LET(levels,SORT(TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:B),1)),
BYROW(levels,LAMBDA(level,HSTACK(level,AVERAGEIF(B2:B,">="&level,A2:A)))))
```

[image]

Comment: This seemed like it was accurate, but now that I am adding new items to the list, I am seeing an issue. Say, I add a new item for lvl 15, it is affecting every row.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10W0FyFjREgr5Pr8GGex29LjlWMbAUEfbs1PKoy_35VE/edit?usp=sharing

The average for level 1 should actually be 6. I'm not sure why I looked past that.

Comment: With <= you can get the desired result with this formula